# how to find sourceCode in omniscient debugger

Tags: debugging

how can i get spring source code ( or other third part souce not the default package) in omniscient debugger; through .debuggerDefaults

I start omniscient debugger in eclilse

Answer (score 0):

after times to research code ;
  omniscient debugger use FileReadr(".debuggerDefaults") to get the file ;
as we know File get path from System.getProperty("user.dir") ; so if u start up  omniscient debugger  in eclipse ; it will find ".debuggerDefaults" file from the path of the  eclipse project path;

```
 for example ,my eclipse project is in D:/maven_project/ , 
and debugger.jar is in c:/downloads ; it will  find ".debuggerDefaults" file from  
  D:/maven_project/ ,but not from c:/downloads
```

and the content of the ".debuggerDefaults" file is

```
SourceDirectory:    "D:/maven_project/src/main/java/"

SourceDirectory:    "C:\Documents and Settings\work\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.2.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE-sources\"
```

`NOTE:`SourceDirectory  must be end of `\` or `/`